# “Hope (this or it) helps?

Tags: terminology, optional-that

Just wondering what's more appropriate, after [reading this conversation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51076/hope-this-help-or-hope-this-helps)

It's *"Hope it helps"* correct? or better "Hope this helps"? Practically, is better to use **it** or **this**?

Or it may depend if we are in USA, UK or Australia?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Hope this help" or "Hope this helps"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51076/hope-this-help-or-hope-this-helps)

Comment: @tenebris2020: There's no discussion of whether or not to use "it" in that question or its answers.

Answer (score 1):

"Hope it helps" is not grammatically wrong. But there is **a strong tradition of using "this"** to refer to exactly *this* particular act of communication (e. g. a letter that we are currently writing).

Some set phrases that are used in letters:

> This is to inform you...
>
> I hope this finds you well...

(if one tries to look for ngrams of "hope this finds you well" and "hope it finds you well", the 2nd variant [is not found **at all**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hope+this+finds+you+well%2Chope+it+finds+you+well&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chope%20this%20finds%20you%20well%3B%2Cc0))

So "Hope this helps" (which is something that, I guess, first appeared in letters and lives on mostly in emails, not in person-to-person "live speech") will follow this tradition and use "this".

Comment: Will be nice to know from where or from which country the "**strong tradition**" you mentioned above is :)

Comment: @SuperAtic Traditions of the English language start from England and spread from there to the whole world. Formal writing exhibits much less variation across different versions of English than everyday speech or slang. So it will be valid for practically all versions of English.

Comment: +1 Although as a footnote (for emphasis): the context of referring to a communication you are writing is important to accurately understand this answer. "Hope it helps" is more prevalent, overall (according to ngrams).

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically speaking **it**, **this**, and **that** are distinguished by their  different meanings.

When you are talking about concrete nouns:

**This**: when you speak about something close to you.

> **This** is my horse (you can tuch it).

**That**= when you speak about something far a little bit but you still see it.

> **That** is my horse (in the corner over there). >

**It**: when you speak about something that's not arounfd you. (Don't be confused with the object pronoun "it" which is same in spelling but different in function. For example in the sentence "I love it", that can talk about a horse that can be here around you, or a little bit far or not haround you at all. )

> **It** is my horse (big, nice, and strong).

When you are talking about **abstractive nouns**:

**This**: when you speak about something that mentioned or  immediately going to be mentioned and you want to emphesize it as if you point on it with your finger .

> **This** is my idea. (=I'm going to mention it or I just finish to mentioned it)
>
> **This** is my idea: we should all go and helppoor people.
>   Or:
>   We should all go and helppoor people. **This** is my idea.

**That**= when you speak about something that 'far' from you by meaning of acception (or when you mention two ideas in which only one you like) or when you mention two or more things and want to refer to the previos one.

> **That** idea does not make sense.

**It**: when you begin to speak about something generally without emphesize:

> **It** is a big mistake to run immediately after heavy eating.
>
> **It** means that you agree with me.

In conclusion, it depends on the context rather than on the country of origin.

> I hope *it* helps.

Can refer to animal such horse. And then it means that you say: I hope that horse can help.

> I hope **this** helps.

This refers to something very specific with emphesize on this rather than others!

You can look at "this" as if it functions as "bold letters" botton. Too much bold letters in a text is not nice. It supposed to be in moderatioon.

In fact, a lot of people don't follow these rules and don't necessarily distinguish between these words.